# Solving stiff system of ODEs with deSolve package in R (vode to ode15s conversion)

Tags: python, r, matlab, numpy, ode

I am trying to solve a large system of stiff ODEs (92 states, 207 parameters) using deSolve package in R (I am using the `vode` solver currently).

I am getting the following error, which tells me that the solver fails to integrate at a very early time step

> dvode -- At T (=R1), and step size H (=R2) the
> corrector converged failed repeatedly
> or with abs(H) = HMIN
> with: R1= 0, R2 = 4.49711e-14
> Warning messages:
> 1: In vode(IC, TIME, Mass_balance, p, mf = 10, maxord = 5) :
> repeated convergence test failures on a step, but integration was successful - inaccurate Jacobian matrix?
> 2: In vode(IC, TIME, Mass_balance, p, mf = 10, maxord = 5) :
> Returning early. Results are accurate, as far as they go

I can solve the same set of equations in MATLAB using their `ode15s` solver using the same tolerances. My questions is there any other solver I should be using from deSolve? I have tried almost all the solvers in the package. I read ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)) that in `scipy` the equivalent of `ode15s` is `scipy.integrator.ode` with the options, `integrator = 'vode'`, `method = 'bdf'` and `maxorder = 5`.

Are there any other set of options I should be using in `vode` in R/deSolve.

My call is the following, `IC` is initial conditions, `TIME` has the time vector, `Mass_balances` has the ODEs and `p` has the parameters, `mf` sets the `method flag`, (this sets the `METH` as `BDF`),`maxord` sets the maximum order at 5.

```
vode(IC, TIME, Mass_balance, p, rtol = 1e-4, atol = 1e-6, mf = 20 ,maxord=5)
```

I am confident that the system of equations does not have other errors as I can solve them using `ode15s`. I am also certain that the system is fairly stiff since ode45 in both R and MATLAB takes a very long time (I did not let it finish after running overnight)

Any help here would be very much appreciated.

The full message from the solver `vode` is pasted below

```
-------------------- 
Time settings 
--------------------
 
  Normal computation of output values of y(t) at t = TOUT 

-------------------- 
Integration settings 
--------------------
 
  Model function an R-function:  
  Jacobian not specified 


-------------------- 
Integration method 
-------------------- 

  1 method flag,    = 22 ; (note: mf = jsv * (10 * meth + miter)) 
  2 jsv             = 1 ; a copy of the Jacobian is saved for reuse in the corrector iteration algorithm 
  3 meth            = 2 ; the basic linear multistep method:
     based on backward differentiation formulas 
  4 miter           = 2 ; chord iteration with an internally generated full Jacobian,
     (NEQ extra calls to F per df/dy value) 
 
dvode -- At T (=R1), and step size H (=R2) the
      corrector converged failed repeatedly
      or with abs(H) = HMIN  
      with: R1= 0, R2 = 1.3093e-10

--------------------

-------------------- 
Time settings 
--------------------
 
  Normal computation of output values of y(t) at t = TOUT 

-------------------- 
Integration settings 
--------------------
 
  Model function an R-function:  
  Jacobian not specified 


-------------------- 
Integration method 
-------------------- 

  1 method flag,    = 22 ; (note: mf = jsv * (10 * meth + miter)) 
  2 jsv             = 1 ; a copy of the Jacobian is saved for reuse in the corrector iteration algorithm 
  3 meth            = 2 ; the basic linear multistep method:
     based on backward differentiation formulas 
  4 miter           = 2 ; chord iteration with an internally generated full Jacobian,
     (NEQ extra calls to F per df/dy value) 
 
dvode -- At T (=R1), and step size H (=R2) the
      corrector converged failed repeatedly
      or with abs(H) = HMIN  
      with: R1= 0, R2 = 1.42211e-12

--------------------
vode return code
--------------------

  return code (idid) =  -5 
  Repeated convergence failures. (Perhaps bad Jacobian supplied or wrong choice of MF or tolerances.)

--------------------
INTEGER values
--------------------

  1 The return code : -5 
  2 The number of steps taken for the problem so far: 0 
  3 The number of function evaluations for the problem so far: 943 
  4 The number of Jacobian evaluations so far: 10 
  5 The method order last used (successfully): 0 
  6 The order of the method to be attempted on the next step: 1 
  7 If return flag =-4,-5: the largest component in error vector 91 
  8 The length of the real work array actually required: 17403 
  9 The length of the integer work array actually required: 121 
 10 The number of matrix LU decompositions so far: 10 
 11 The number of nonlinear (Newton) iterations so far: 30 
 12 The number of convergence failures of the solver so far  10 
 13 The number of error test failures of the integrator so far: 0 
 
--------------------
RSTATE values
--------------------

  1 The step size in t last used (successfully): 0 
  2 The step size to be attempted on the next step: 1.42211e-12 
  3 The current value of the independent variable which the solver has reached: 0 
  4 Tolerance scale factor > 1.0 computed when requesting too much accuracy: 0 
 
Warning messages:
1: In vode(IC, TIME, Mass_balance, p, mf = 22, rtol = 1e-04, atol = 1e-04,  :
  repeated convergence test failures on a step, but integration was successful - inaccurate Jacobian matrix?
2: In vode(IC, TIME, Mass_balance, p, mf = 22, rtol = 1e-04, atol = 1e-04,  :
  Returning early. Results are accurate, as far as they go
```

Comment: Yes, `order = 15` in scipy options. I specify `maxord = 5` in `vode` options.

Comment: The suggestion to use `order = 15` on `http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users` is a mistake.  The maximum order of the `vode` solver in scipy is 5.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Any ideas regarding the code options?

Comment: You could try `mf=22`, but that's a shot in the dark.  Do you get a similar error with any of the other `deSolve` solvers (e.g. `lsoda`, `radau`, `daspk`)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried all the three, and for all of them R does finish solving the system, but the result is all `NA`, except the initial time point.  For `lsode` and `vode`, the solver fails and reports results only for the first two time points (`mf = 22`was also tried with the same result).

Comment: Has any one used `Rsundials` package from CRAN, I don't understand it's usage (in particular, how to specify the `package` variable when the ODEs are defined as an R function). Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Have you explicitly checked that, for a given time and state, your R implementation of `Mass_balance` returns the same values as your matlab implementation?  That is, don't call the solver, just call `Mass_balance` in R and matlab, and check that the vectors that are returned are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it seems the solver in R fails to start - I can check at different times in MATLAB, I will have to use those state variables as input to check in the `Mass_balance`. In case you are interested, I can paste full message from the `vode`